# Is it possible to rotate d3.js xAxis using .orient?

Tags: svg, d3.js

[image]

I'd like to rotate all the date on the xAxis.

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b %d"));
```

There are already some posts on it, like this one: [How to rotate the text labels for the x Axis of a d3.js graph](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/how-to-rotate-text-labels-for-x-axis-of.html)

I would like to know if there's a better way, say using the `.orient()` function?

On the documentation it says:

> If the specified orientation is not one of the supported values, the axis reverts to the default orientation. Changing the orientation affects the position of the ticks and their labels in relation to the axis path, but does not change the position of the axis itself; to change the position of the axis with respect to the plot, specify a transform attribute on the containing g element.

I'd like to know how exactly I could do that. Thanks very much!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. As the documentation says, `.orient()` doesn't actually rotate the axis. So if that's your question, the answer is no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, `axis.orient` only accepts four arguments: `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` and the default orientation is the `bottom` one.

One cannot take mix and match properties from different orientations or do other complicated operations on the labels.

The approach taken in the post you refer to is the recommended way to do it.